# React-Datepicker layout broken inside a Bootstrap-React Modal (calendar truncated)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-datepicker

I'm using [React Datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) inside a [Bootstrap React Modal](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) dialog.

Getting the following layout issue when clicking the text box to open the calendar:

[image]

The basic code is this:

```
                      <Modal show={this.state.isDialogOpenB} onHide={this.handleDialogCloseB}>
                        <Modal.Header closeButton>
                          <Modal.Title>Editing UserID: {this.state.activeItemIdB} Username: {this.state.activeItemNameB}</Modal.Title>
                        </Modal.Header>
                        <Modal.Body>
                            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="bChkboxLocked"></input>
                                <label class="custom-control-label" htmlFor="bChkboxLocked">Locked</label>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <DatePicker dateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy" selected={this.state.testDate} onChange={this.handleDatePickerChangeB} />
                            </div>
                        </Modal.Body>
                        <Modal.Footer>
                          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleDialogCloseB}>
                            Close
                          </Button>
                        </Modal.Footer>
                      </Modal>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a lot of time to debug this, but I found a better datepicker that doesn't depend on its outer DIV: [React Day-Picker](https://react-day-picker.js.org/) :

[image]